# Is it possible to have parent (not base) and child localization on iOS?

Tags: ios, localization

I want to localize only few words for a specific language. Is it possible to extent parent language (not base localization), instead of creating a new localization file? For exsample I have Dutch as whole localization file and want to replace some strings for Dutch (Netherlands).

Comment: are you using `NSLocalizedString`?

Comment: Yes, i'm using `NSString *text = NSLocalizedString(@"some key", nil);`.